# How to restart a Python script if it freezes and does not raise any Exception

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am running a python script where I use the WebDriver get() method, which is known to freeze sometimes, without raising any exception.
This is a well known issue of selenium module, as you can read below:
[discussion 1](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10336)
[discussion 2](https://groups.google.com/g/webdriver/c/hr5e9XYYoPY?pli=1)

I tried many of the solutions on the web (eg. setting the set_page_load_timeout) but had no luck.
So, my only option is to restart the script when it gets stuck on the get() method for a given amount of time.
What is the best way of doing that?
Please find a simplified code below:

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

TIMEOUT = 10
options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_argument(f'user-data-dir={DATA["user_data_dir"]}')
chrome_driver = ChromeDriverManager().install()
driver = Chrome(service=Service(chrome_driver), options=options)
# driver.set_page_load_timeout(TIMEOUT)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, TIMEOUT)
driver.get('https://www.stackoverflow.com/')
```

Comment: What do you mean by `get()` method gets freeze? Can you give us some examples of pages where this happens? Maybe this is because of heavy scripts running on that page?

Comment: Possibly due to an infinitely loading page... but timeout will eventually be reached. (default depends on the driver, but can be pretty long...  5 minutes or so) If you get such a timeout it's worth noting that another .get() will be needed before any other driver methods can be executed.  (and probably to a different URL, or you'll continue having an issue)   This might seem obvious, but have you try/catched the.get() call?

Comment: Thank you for the help guys. When I say it freezes I mean the execution just hangs on the get method. The program just stops and nothing happens. Eventually a timeout exception is raised, but it may take up to 5-10 minutes and I don't want to wait that long. Unfortunately, setting a shorter timeout with set_page_load_timeout does not work. The problem happens on this url: https://www.merrjep.al/krijonjoftim

Comment: you can change the page load strategy, but you should remember that the only thing that will work after this happens is another .get(): https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/options/#pageloadstrategy  You will also need to use proper webdriverwaits or sleeps if setting to "none".  (could also need some handling of stale element errors depending on what you are doing)